# Cron job not working - Can't see in the queue attached

Tags: wp-cron, cron

I have a custom schedule defined for a cron job to be triggered. This is how my code looks:

```
<?php
//wp-config
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);

//Plugin file
register_activation_hook( '__FILE__', 'activate' );

function activate() {
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_hourly_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'everyminute', 'my_hourly_event' );
    }
}

add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'add_cron_schedule' );

function add_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $period = get_option( 'my_period', true );
    $schedules['everyminute'] = array(
        'interval' => MINUTE_IN_SECONDS * $period,
        'display' => __('My Schedule')
    );

    return $schedules;
}

add_action( 'my_hourly_event',  'cron_data_update' );

function cron_data_update() {
    //THIS NEVER RUNS!
    update_option( 'cron-check', 'Ran', 'no' );
}
```

This is the Linux cron that triggers it:

```
*/2 * * * * wget -q -O – http://somedomain.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron
```

Besides that, I don't see my event being listed in the gui:

[image]

The calls are never done. I cannot see that option in the database! Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: You disabled the `wp_cron`  than how it will work.

Comment: The tutorials I followed say that you have to disable it from wp-config. I am using a Linux cron job to trigger cron.

Comment: There are two options.  One is to disable so cron and use your server cron manager.  Second using wp-cron.  But you mixed two things

Comment: Remove the disable option  and check it again.  Than post your comment

Comment: If I am using a server to trigger the cron, then I have to disable it. Hold on, I'll post the cron job.